# Can you take the shortcut on Koopa Troopa Beach without items?

Tags: mario-kart-64

On Koopa Troopa Beach, there is a secret cave shortcut to skip half the course. Usually to take the shortcut, you need to jump off the ramp with a Mushroom or Star.

Is it possible to take the shortcut on Koopa Troopa Beach without using items? If yes, can it be done outside of 150cc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can take the shortcut it in every mode without an item. Doing a [Mini-Turbo](http://mariokart.wikia.com/wiki/Mini-Turbo) before going onto the ramp helps to increase your speed. Also jumping at the peak of the ramp can help on the slower speeds.

[Here's a 50cc 1p GP mode example](https://clips.twitch.tv/EagerPeacefulBisonCharlieBitMe)

Also you actually don't need the ramp at all to get into the tunnel.

[Here's an example of that in 150cc 4p VS mode while small from a lightning hit (top right screen [player 2])](https://youtu.be/2PsIt9b0ZHc?t=8m57s)

Comment: I think you only need the mini-turbo for 50cc and 100cc. [DanmakuGrazer's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/332232/181240) shows the jump in 150cc without any mini-turbos.

Comment: Just tested and I was able to make the jump (using the ramp) with no mini-turbo in 50cc (1p GP). Helps to use a lightweight though since they are the fastest (Yoshi/Toad/Peach). You also have to jump at the very top of the ramp.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. [As shown here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-cJLDatDWY).

Comment: Is this only possible on 150cc?

Comment: Probably due to the need of speed